# Использование параметра шаблона в качестве параметра шаблона другого класса

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Есть такой код:

```
template< typename T>                                                                                                                                                                                              
class A                                                                                                                                                                                                            
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
public:                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  typedef std::map<int, typename T*>::const_iterator Const_iterator;                                                                                                                                               

};
```

g++ 7.3.0 выдает такую ошибку:

> ```
> main.cpp:8:36: error: template argument 2 is invalid
>    typedef std::map<int, typename T*>::const_iterator Const_iterator;
> ```

В чем причина?

Comment: Что такое `typename T*`? Зачем вы туда засунули слово `typename`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
typedef typename std::map<int, T*>::const_iterator Const_iterator;
```

Или

```
using Const_iterator = typename std::map<int,  T*>::const_iterator;
```

У вас две ошибки - во-первых, `typename` при вполне объявленном параметре типа `T` не нужен, а во-вторых, он нужен для указания того, что зависимое имя является типом.